# Django Rest Framework upload multiply images at once with serializer

Tags: python, django, image, rest, file-upload

I had some research on web for this problem on DRF. When one image is in post DRF works great. But when 3 or 5 images are in one post there is problem that Django save only first image from POST query and others are not saved in database.
The question is how to properly handle multiply images upload in one post.

## Description

> Django version

- 1.10

> Rest framework version

- 3.4.6

> Python version

- 3.5

Here is my code what I was trying to do:

## models

```
class UserModel(AbstractEmailUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    details = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='avatar')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

class UserImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('UserModel',related_name='user')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Here in models I have related field from User to UserImages. For purpose on POST query from postman I manual add ID from user to handle FK.

## serializer

```
class SerializerUserImages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserImages

    def create(self, validated_data):
        imgs = UserImages.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return imgs
```

Maybe here I must do some for loop to accomplish save method for multiply images.

## views

```
class UploadImages(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)

    @parser_classes((FormParser, MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser))
    def post(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = SerializerUserImages(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data={"msg": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(data={"msg": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

All parsers are included for handling this post query.

This is output from **request.data** = `<QueryDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: top_20_cro.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: images.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'user': ['2', '2']}>`

This is copy of request POST from POSTMAN:

```
POST /api/images/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTQ3MjIwMTcwMSwiZXhwIjoxNDcyMjMxNzAxLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmluLmJyZWthbG9AZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJtYXJpbi5icmVrYWxvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.Fi3kmXJ44E_qhHHioniQ-cqri-u2ELU-XmpE_1oJ4Fk
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1e53ac06-ed37-ff6e-2dc5-117976b86a5e
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

2
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

image
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

2
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

image
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

How can this be handled without some great magic, is there some easy logic that I missed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my some logic about this problem, so I hope someone will use this code (hack) for this purpose:

## Serializer change

```
class SerializerTest(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(required=True))


    def create(self, validated_data):

        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'image':
                for x in value:
                    c = UserImages.objects.create(image=x, user_id=UserModel.objects.get(id=self.context['request'].user.id).id)
                    c.save()
        return validated_data
```

I have updated my serialzer for just one field **img**. And use for loop to extract images from POST. As you can see i call query to store images to database on FK user. This work's very good.

## Views

```
class UploadImages(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)

    @parser_classes((FormParser, MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser))
    def post(self, request, format=None):



        serializer = SerializerTest(data=request.data, context={'request':request})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            if len(serializer.data['image']) > 0:
                que = UserImages.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
                ser = SerializerUserImages(que, many=True)
                return Response(data={"msg": ser.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(data={"msg": 'Provide images!'}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        else:
            return Response(data={"msg": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting filenames for your images, I mean replace `filename=""` with something like `filename="image-1"`, `filename="image-2"`, etc. Files should have different filenames or they override each other.

Comment: After that same issue.

Comment: print `serializer.data` in your post method and see if it contains all files or not.

Comment: Here is output: <QueryDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: top_20_cro.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: images.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'user': ['2', '2'], 'filename': ['image-1', 'image-2']}>

Comment: Reading your question it's not possible the way you're trying to do easily :D As far as I know the standard html form is not to create multiple objects at once. You should either go with hacky ways (parsing `serializer.data` and create objects yourself) or use rest api and base64 encode your files to achieve this (using bulk commands in rest api.)

Comment: First I thought your problem is sending multiple files, now that I read your question in details and seeing the result of the print function I see your problem is not sending files, it's creating multiple objects with a single multipart form.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
many=True
```

with the serializer initializer. For eg.:

```
serializer = SerializerUserImages(data=request.data, many=True)
```

This should do the trick.

Also have a look at [ListSerializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)

Comment: why not? isn't that the purpose of it?

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly is the issue showing up. Also, did you try using the web interface provided by DRF before using POSTMAN?